# I am running this code but it gives error that i can't understand

Tags: xetex, tex-gyre-math

```
    \documentclass{article}    
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
    \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

    \begin{document}
    Linear equation \(\sqrt{x+y}=2\) 
    \end{document}
```

When i run this code it with xelatex it gives the follwing error

```
"(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> EU1/TeXGyreTermesMath(2)/bx/n on input

line 4.

! Undefined control sequence.

\um_set_mathcode:nnn #1#2#3->\Umathcode

\int_eval:n {#1}=\mathchar@type #2\c...

l.4 \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

The control sequence at the end of the top line

of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have

misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct

spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,

and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation."

...
l.4 \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.

If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.

Missing character: There is no ^^@ in font TeX Gyre Termes/ICU:script=latn;lang

uage=DFLT;!

! Undefined control sequence.

\um_set_mathcode:nnn #1#2#3->\Umathcode

\int_eval:n {#1}=\mathchar@type #2\c...

l.4 \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

The control sequence at the end of the top line

of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have

misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct

spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,

and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


Missing character: There is no ^^@ in font TeX Gyre Termes/ICU:script=latn;lang

uage=DFLT;!
```

Comment: Old versions of xetex called this command xetexmathcode (I think) recent versions use the Umathcode name, matching luatex. So it seems you have a new unicode-math package and an old xetex?

Comment: No error here on my Texlive 2014 system.  Perhaps you have something missing from your installation.

Comment: i have installed miktex 2.94407 and i am running this program in tex maker. Package manager shows this date 2013-02-19 for xetex package and this date 2014-07-12 for unicode-math. Now what should i do to run the program (get new xetex package or use some other commands?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to non up-to-date software

Comment: The issue is due to using an updated version of `unicode-math` over an older TeX distribution.